# Integer parts isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, model-theory, ordered-fields

Let $F$ be a real closed field. It is known$^{[1]}$ that $F$ has an integer part, that is, a subring $A$ such that $\forall x \in F, \exists ! a \in A,  a \leq x < a+1$.

Are all integer parts over $F$ isomorphic as ordered rings?

$[1]$: M. H. Mourgues and J. P. Ressayre
The Journal of Symbolic Logic
Vol. 58, No. 2 (Jun., 1993), pp. 641-647

Real closed fields are fields in which $X^2 + 1$ is irreductible and $F[X] / (X^2 + 1)$ is algebraically closed. They are ordered by setting $x \geq 0$ iff $x$ is a square.

---

A few ideas:

-Every order preserving isomorphism between two integer parts in $F$ extends in a unique way as an automorphism of $F$.

-Integer parts of real closed fields are exactly models of open induction (PA with induction scheme restricted to quantifier-free formulas).

-If $G$ is a subgroup of $(F,+)$ such that $\forall x \in F, \exists ! g \in G, g \leq x < g+1$ then the group $(F,+) / G$ is isomorphic to the "torus" $([0;1[_F,\underline{+})$ where $x\underline{+}y = x+y \ \mod 1$. This torus need not be isomorphic to ${{\mathbb{S}}^1}_F = \{(x,y) \in F^2 \ | \ x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$ with $(x,y)\underline{.}(z,t) = (x.z-y.t,x.t+y.z)$.

-No integer part over $F$ is definable in $(F,+,.,0,1)$.

Comment: Are you saying $F$ is a sub field of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @DavidHill Not all [real closed fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field) are subfields of $\mathbb{R}$. If a real closed field is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$, then the question is trivial, because it's only integer part is $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Can you give a definition or classification of the relevant fields?

Comment: @DavidHill Did you follow my link to wikipedia? The definition there is very clear, in fact 9 equivalent definitions are given! However, a reasonable classification of real closed fields is unlikely... For all infinite cardinals $\kappa$ there are $2^\kappa$ (the maximum number) real closed fields of size $\kappa$ up to isomorphism.

Comment: @AlexKruckman There is always a homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to F$ given by sending $1\in\mathbb{Z}$ to $1_F\in F$. It would be useful for non-experts to see an example where this map is not injective (assuming there is one).

Comment: This map is always injective (since ordered fields always have characteristic $0$). The issue is that $F$ might be non-Archimedian, i.e. there is an element $a\in F$ such that $a>n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. For example, the ordered field $\mathbb{R}(x)$ where $x > r$ for all $r\in \mathbb{R}$ has a real closure, which is non-Archimedian.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30924/discussion-between-david-hill-and-alex-kruckman).

Comment: What do you mean by isomorphic? Order-isomorphic or isomorphic as rings?

Comment: I mean isomorphic as rings.

Comment: @SMM: I edited: I am rather interested in ordered ring isomorphisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gurgen Asatryan proved in 2008 in *On Ordered Fields with Infinitely Many Integer Parts* that some ordered fields such as ${\mathbb{R}((x))}^{\mathbb{Q}}$ have $2^{\aleph_0}$ integer parts with distinct existential theories so the answer to my question is no.